How to download a image using requests
I have to download and image using Python requests. I logged into the website and followed each session when I clicked the image link from the network section, I got a post session with URL.
("https://www.xender.com/xender/WorkOrderAction.do").
This is a sample example URL which won't work. I have attached a code with the session I have received from the network. But I am unable to download the image.Is there any solution.
get_image_details = s.post("https://www.xender.com/xender/WorkOrderAction.do",
                           files={"jspName": "jsp/VC_WO_View_Screen.jsp",
                                  "originalJSPName": "jsp/VC_WO_View_Screen.jsp", "doAction": "", "xmlName": "",
                                  "originalXmlName": "", "showTabName": "", "hdnRequestValue": "1", "hdnBackValue": "0",
                                  "hdnVistaHelpFile": "help/Begin.html?&context=pay_help&topic=Begin.html",
                                  "AUTO_REFRESH_TREE": "", "HDN_QUERY_COMMENTS": "", "BROWSER_TYPE": "",
                                  "hdnSaveGroupMessage": "", "hdnConfirmSaveGrpExecution": "",
                                  "hdnAlertSaveGroupExecuted": "", "hdnClickedButtonName": "",
                                  "HDN_NEXT_PREV_BUTTON": "", "HDN_NEXT_PREV_ACTION": "", "HDN_NEXT_PREV_ACTION": "",
                                  "HDN_ROW_NUMBER_CLICKED": "", "HDN_ROW_COUNT": "", "HDN_ROW_CLICKED": "",
                                  "HDN_LEFT_PANEL_SHOW": "", "id": "36581", "sPriority": "Routine",
                                  "sCategory": "Appliances", "sSubCategory": "Washer/Dryer", "sPropRef": "atl00985",
                                  "sPropName": "3807 Rosebud Park Dr",
                                  "addressString": "3807 Rosebud Park Dr, \r\nSnellville, GA, 30039", "sBuilding": "",
                                  "sFloor": "", "sUnit": "ATL00985", "sLocation": "", "sAsset": "", "sOKToEnter": "Yes",
                                  "sAccessNotes": "NTE $250", "lblDtCall": "08/29/2024", "occupantCode": "t0008116",
                                  "Occupant": "Francine Jones", "callerName": "Francine Jones",
                                  "callerEmail": "enjoiserenityja@live.com", "callerPhone": "4049339111",
                                  "sBriefDesc": "WASHER & DRYER DISPOSAL",
                                  "sProblemDesc": "Remove washer & dryer immediately", "sWoStatus": "Assigned External",
                                  "sWoCompletedStatus": "Vendor Completed", "dNotToExceedAmt": "0.00", "hour": "05",
                                  "minute": "20", "meridian": "PM",
                                  "sTechNotes": work_orders["sTechNotes"],
                                  "sVendorNotes": "", "file": "(binary)", "attachType": "", "task": "FILEDOWNLOAD",
                                  "hdnFileId": "360577", "hdnVcAttachHmy": "0",
                                  "hdnFileName": "WorkOrder_36581_0_image.jpg", "propsalID": "27463", "woID": "36581",
                                  "woTabName": "AssignedWO", "objVenPartyId": "2232816", "hdnAttachmentType": "",
                                  "CURRENT_MODAL_DIALOG_FLAG": "Yes", "hdnOnSiteSchelDt": "",
                                  "menuCaption": "Work Orders", "hdnRequestJspValue": "9"},
                           headers={"priority": "u=0, i"}) 
print(get_image_details.content)
with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
     file.write(get_image_details.content)
                                       

